# How to create linux terminal like tutorialspoint?

Tags: node.js, linux, shell

[TutorialsPoint Java Compiler](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php)

In tutorialspoint, they have created linux terminal using [term.js](https://github.com/chjj/term.js/).

I have integrated same github library in my project, it is working fine but I am trying to understand the flow of tutorialspoint.

My assumption:

- In tutroialspoint each time they are creating new user_id under root user(cg) and running terminal(nodejs server) using that user_id so every time when you reload page there will be a different user_id (run `whoami` in terminal), so another user can't operate other users files.

I am running nodejs server using [forever.js](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) under root user, I want to implement same type of functionality. What is correct way to do this? and if there is another way please elaborate.

Comment: I think they are creating a new user each time you visit the page and providing you a subshell of that user. It can be easily achieve by using Shell Programming techniques.

Comment: Creating a new user each time thing is probably nothing more than a security measure.

Comment: yes, i know it can be done using shell scripting, but i am not able to found any documentation on this.

Answer (score 1):

I think they are creating a new user each time you visit the page and providing you a subshell of that user. It can be easily achieve by using Shell Programming techniques. Creating a new user each time thing is probably nothing more than a security measure.

So I will briefly explain the concept in 5 steps:

1 - Create a new user:

```
shell_exec('useradd --expiredate 2016-09-10 [username]');
```

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/useradd.htm

2 - Login to this newly created user account:

```
shell_exec('su [username]');
```

3 - Get user input to the PHP script using AJAX(dynamically).

4 - Execute user's command and send the output to user:

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec("[user's command]");
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

5 - Repeat from 3.